# SQL Server: Avoid simultaneous updates increasing a column value over its target

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server table called `AD` where ad's to be viewed are stored as

```
create table Sponsors.AD
(
    ADID varchar(40) primary key,
    SponsorID varchar(30),
    PurchasedViews int , --How many views the ad must reach before it is disabled
    CurrentViewCount int, --Keeps track of how many views the ad has gotten
{...}
    Active bit -- for easier checking of whether the AD still has clicks to give
)
```

This feeds into a webpage where, to access a feature, users first need to view an ad. Users can pick one ad from a menu that displays three options [they pick one, the ad's media is displayed and the feature is unlocked at the conclusion].
After they view the ad, its `CurrentViewCount` should be updated (increased by 1).

This is handled by a stored procedure that includes an update call for the table - separate from the stored procedure that fetches 3 ads at random for the option menu - but I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve the problem of synchronizing all concurrent `AD` views - as it could happen that

1. two or more users have the same ad in their 3-choice-menu
2. two or more users view the same ad at the same time

1 and 2 are not a problem on their own but they could be if the ad is one click away from it's set maximum.

One way I've thought to solve this is to set the active flag as false if the ad is one click away from it's target when it is displayed in the 3-option menu, and if the user does not click it, the flag will be reset to true -- but then I'd need to handle cases where the user exits the option dialogue or disconnects, times out, etc. I feel like there must be a better way.

Another suggestion I've heard is to automatically increase the counter when the ads are summoned to the 3-option menu but that's even more overhead than the other and suffers the same issues.

Locking the table is absolutely infeasible unless we wanted to only serve one ad view at a time - so I'm not even considering it.

I'm sure something like this has been discussed before but don't know what keywords/etc to search to find more on this.

Comment: Is it really so critical that an ad is shown few times more than purchased? While most likely it is possible to guarantee exact number of views, it could be rather difficult to implement. Roughly, how many simultaneous users you have and how many ads in total? In other words, what are the chances that the same ad is presented to 1, 2, 3, 4, ...etc users simultaneously?

Comment: If you use an active flag then are you saying it can only be displayed as an option if the active flag is false? Wouldn't that mean that for any ad, it is only displayed to one user?  More generally, you should clarify the requirements before finding a solution.   In particular, do you wish to simultaneously display the ad as an option to multiple users. For example if the ad has 100 views left, would you want to display it as an option to 5 users?

Comment: First, clarify the requirements. There are many options:

Comment: It seems that there is no way around the possibility that an ad option choice can become invalid at some time. You can impose a fixed time limit or you can say it becomes invalid if the ad views has reached its limit.. Then  decide what to do if an ad option becomes invalid.  There is probably no way to avoid having the user click on an ad that has become invalid, but you can avoid that happening somewhat by removing it from the front end.  For invalid ads, you can let the user pass through or present the options again. Once you clarify i will suggest a solution.

Comment: This is a good question. Have you seen my comments?

Answer (score 0):

I would not count the clicks within the same table... Could avoid your locking issues...

But, to get to your question: maybe you could handle this "fuzzy". Not the thight active=yes/no but rather something like an InactivityLevel together with a timeout.

As long as your flag would be true, everything is fine. If the counter exceeds, you switch to "No new visitors" and set a timestamp, so your add won't display in a new context. You set this to "inactive" after a given timeout.

Comment: The real table where views are properly counted is another, this table just has those values for quicker querying.
I considered timestamps but then I'd need to have a process that keeps checking for ads that were disabled at one view from their target and never had that last view counted and reenable them. I mean, all in all It wouldn't have too much impact so maybe I should.

Comment: As you will never know for sure who is your last visitor and when he'll terminate his sessions this could be necessary...